# Mongodb Date Query - using java driver not returning results

Tags: mongodb

This is my collection in mongodb

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58553f0318e2893724222cdb"),
        "name" : "abc",
        "datetime" : ISODate("2017-01-23T10:50:50.574Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58553f0318e2893724222cdb"),
        "name" : "abc",
        "datetime" : ISODate("2016-01-23T10:50:50.574Z")
}

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58553f0318e2893724222cdb"),
        "name" : "abc",
        "datetime" : ISODate("2015-01-23T10:50:50.574Z")
}
```

Im querying this collection using java driver as below,

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("collection");
Document DateFilter = new Document("datetime", new Document("$gt",new Date()));
int count = collection.find(DateFilter).size();
```

count is returning 0. (it should have returned 1)
no matter what range I use, 0 is returned always

DateFilter.toJson(), the following is returned

```
{ "datetime" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : 1482524040000 } } }
```

When I query the mongodb shell directly using this above json as filter, nothing is returned.

When I use the below json as filter, correct result is returned

```
{"datetime" : { "$gt" :  ISODate("2016-12-24T20:56:05.423Z") } }
```

Comment: why all of documents have same id ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I was actually using skip with more than the total count of the collection, which is why it did not return anything.